# How to trigger a run Book in azure automation account yearly once or twice

Tags: azure, azure-runbook, runbook

We have a recruitment where we need to run Automation Runbook Quarterly or Once in a year or twice in a year. But, by default we have only till month. Is there any other way trigger the runbook as mentioned above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the month interval parameter with the value 3, it will be run every 3rd month, that will be once a quarter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationschedule?view=azps-10.1.0